# How to use pre-trained model combined with CNN/LSTM/RNN for text classification？Such as BERT+LSTM

Tags: python, machine-learning, text-classification, bert-language-model

I'm currently using pre-trained models like **BERT/ERNIE/albert/xlnet/roberta/t5/gpt** for text classification, but I want to compare BERT/ERNIE/albert/xlnet/roberta/t5/gpt for word vector training, **CNN/LSTM /RNN**, etc. to do classification, how should I do it, is there a relevant introduction and code link?

Comment: tensorflow or pytorch?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.